# "...Тропа, замощённая в три камня" - я не понимаю техники мощения, всё ли верно?

Tags: выбор-слов

> Из этого города и начинается древняя тропа по горам, замощённая в три
>   камня.

Comment: (С точки зрения техники мощения, не более.) Имеется в виду ширина тропы. Так говорят — "дорога, вымощенная в две плиты", например.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это мощение обеспечивает минимально необходимую перевязку укладки камней дорожки или соприкосновение не менее трёх граней (трёх четвертей периметра) каждого камня с соседними.